# How to fix "one problem on race condition check which using go-build-race tools"?

Tags: go, concurrency, race-condition

At first, I know the code has some race condition , so I used "go build -race" command to check it and I want to see how the result shows, when I run, at the first time, it shows the one result as follows, and then run again shows the second one, it has two different results, and I don't know why, and is any one can tell me the reason, and how the code was executed ?, Thanks a lot very much.

**Source Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

var (
    counter int
    wg sync.WaitGroup
)

func main() {
    wg.Add(2)

    go incCounter(1)
    go incCounter(2)

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("Final Counter:", counter)

}

func incCounter(id int) {
    defer wg.Done()

    for count := 0; count < 2; count++ {
        value := counter
        // switch goroutine
        runtime.Gosched()
        value++
        counter = value
    }
}
```

When I use go build -race tool to check race condition, it shows two different results ,as follows:

**One Result:**

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x0000005fb2d0 by goroutine 7:
  main.incCounter()
      D:/Go/projects/hello-world/src/concurrency/list7/m.go:34 +0x97

Previous read at 0x0000005fb2d0 by goroutine 6:
  main.incCounter()
      D:/Go/projects/hello-world/src/concurrency/list7/m.go:30 +0x76

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      D:/Go/projects/hello-world/src/concurrency/list7/m.go:18 +0x90

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      D:/Go/projects/hello-world/src/concurrency/list7/m.go:17 +0x6f
==================
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x0000005fb2d0 by goroutine 6:
  main.incCounter()
      D:/Go/projects/hello-world/src/concurrency/list7/m.go:34 +0x97

Previous write at 0x0000005fb2d0 by goroutine 7:
  main.incCounter()
      D:/Go/projects/hello-world/src/concurrency/list7/m.go:34 +0x97

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      D:/Go/projects/hello-world/src/concurrency/list7/m.go:17 +0x6f

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      D:/Go/projects/hello-world/src/concurrency/list7/m.go:18 +0x90
==================
Final Counter: 2
Found 2 data race(s)
```

**Second Result:**

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x0000005fb2d0 by goroutine 7:
  main.incCounter()
      D:/Go/projects/hello-world/src/concurrency/list7/m.go:30 +0x76

Previous write at 0x0000005fb2d0 by goroutine 6:
  main.incCounter()
      D:/Go/projects/hello-world/src/concurrency/list7/m.go:34 +0x97

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      D:/Go/projects/hello-world/src/concurrency/list7/m.go:18 +0x90

Goroutine 6 (finished) created at:
  main.main()
      D:/Go/projects/hello-world/src/concurrency/list7/m.go:17 +0x6f
==================
Final Counter: 4
Found 1 data race(s)
```

They are the two different results.

Comment: i recently wrote about some of these issues and why the race detector would do this :p https://medium.com/dm03514-tech-blog/golang-candidates-and-contexts-a-heuristic-approach-to-race-condition-detection-e2b230e70d08

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to explore scheduling in go (good article from [ardanlabs](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2018/08/scheduling-in-go-part2.html)).

The short answer is you don't control an execution order, go runtime does. Each execution of the same program won’t produce the same execution trace. [Race detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector) tracks "racy" behaviour on each run and results directly depend on the decision of the scheduler.